# MySQL - Extract datetime and convert into matrix mapping

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have huge amount of MySQL record data and must be tranformed like this :

[image: Datetime matrix mapping]

My question is, how to extract datetime value (month, week, hour) and insert it into exact column with binary value (0 or 1) as image above.

**PROBLEM SOLVED**, i just figured out the easiest way, here for the example:

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET h1 = CASE WHEN (SELECT DAYOFWEEK (trx_datetime)) = '1' THEN 1 
         ELSE '0'
         END
, h2 = CASE WHEN (SELECT DAYOFWEEK (trx_datetime)) = '2' THEN '1' 
         ELSE '0' 
         END
, h3 = CASE WHEN (SELECT DAYOFWEEK (trx_datetime)) = '3' THEN '1' 
         ELSE '0' 
         END
, h4 = CASE WHEN (SELECT DAYOFWEEK (trx_datetime)) = '4' THEN '1' 
         ELSE '0' 
         END
, h5 = CASE WHEN (SELECT DAYOFWEEK (trx_datetime)) = '5' THEN '1' 
         ELSE '0' 
         END
, h6 = CASE WHEN (SELECT DAYOFWEEK (trx_datetime)) = '6' THEN '1' 
         ELSE '0' 
         END
, h7 = CASE WHEN (SELECT DAYOFWEEK (trx_datetime)) = '7' THEN '1' 
         ELSE '0' 
         END
         ;
```

Comment: How your current table is formatted? Also, you will find this useful: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: its just denormalize table from star schema with large record, for some reason i need to extract trx datetime value and insert into exact column. for example : 
IF datetime value is 2015/10/08 17:31 
THEN insert into column H17=1
ELSE column=0.

Usually, i extract datetime value with this:
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH/WEEK/HOUR FROM Datetime_Column
Or
SELECT MONTH/WEEK/HOUR (Datetime_Column) FROM TABLE

Is there proper way to insert datetime extraction value with CASE/IF into multiple column??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEM SOLVED**, i just figured out the easiest way, here for the example:

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET h1 = CASE WHEN (SELECT DAYOFWEEK (trx_datetime)) = '1' THEN 1 
         ELSE '0'
         END
, h2 = CASE WHEN (SELECT DAYOFWEEK (trx_datetime)) = '2' THEN '1' 
         ELSE '0' 
         END
, h3 = CASE WHEN (SELECT DAYOFWEEK (trx_datetime)) = '3' THEN '1' 
         ELSE '0' 
         END
, h4 = CASE WHEN (SELECT DAYOFWEEK (trx_datetime)) = '4' THEN '1' 
         ELSE '0' 
         END
, h5 = CASE WHEN (SELECT DAYOFWEEK (trx_datetime)) = '5' THEN '1' 
         ELSE '0' 
         END
, h6 = CASE WHEN (SELECT DAYOFWEEK (trx_datetime)) = '6' THEN '1' 
         ELSE '0' 
         END
, h7 = CASE WHEN (SELECT DAYOFWEEK (trx_datetime)) = '7' THEN '1' 
         ELSE '0' 
         END
         ;
```